# ShellExecute Adobe Reader XI Security Warning Dialog Settings

Tags: shellexecute, adobe-reader

I have a program which shells (using ShellExecute) Adobe Reader to open an FDF with a linked PDF on a mapped drive. The program inserts registry settings to setup the trusted locations prior to calling Reader. This worked fine up to version X but now fails on version XI. I have managed to fix the problem which is down to needing to replace the mapped paths for trusted locations with UNC paths (change 'm:\folder\subfolder' to '\server\mappedfolder\folder\subfolder')  but there is another issue as well.

When you open an FDF with a linked PDF from a network location in Adobe Reader XI there is a 'Security Warning' dialog that asks you to 'Allow' or 'Block' the PDF file. If the PDF file is allowed the the dialog is not shown again so presumably the file name is stored somewhere but not in the 'Privileged Locations' settings.

**Where does Adobe Reader store the list of files that have been 'Allowed'?** Alternatively, how can I find out what files/settings have changed when I click 'Allow'.

Note that the trusted folders/privileged locations are stored in the registry here: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\11.0\TrustManager\cTrustedFolders but that this particular dialog does not alter these settings.

To reproduce the exact problem use a Windows 7 PC with Adobe Reader XI. Create a mapped network drive that maps to a shared folder on the same PC with full permission for Everyone (e.g. M:\ maps to c:\AdobeTest). Put on FDF that links to a PDF in the folder and open the FDF with a command line or shell from an application.

Comment: I have the exact same issue with Adobe Reader DC on a Win 10 machine. A FDF file with a link to the PDF inside. Both files are on the Desktop but I still get the Security warning! Any news here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be no documentation on this.